# iOS development- removing inline image

Tags: image, ios, encoding

Recently playing around with the open source iphone app code, and found it uses base64 image.

Any way for me to decode this in order to see the actual content?

```
        div#relatedwikihows>h2>span:before {
            content: url(data:image/gif;base64,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);
            margin-right: 6px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are various posts on Stackoverflow that talk about this.

Also found, http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2010/04/20/encrypting-decrypting-base64-encode-decode-in-iphone-objective-c/

It would seem the issue will be to extract the content string from the CSS like string you have in your post.